# How to check which theme is being used in a magento based website.

Tags: magento2, theme

Suppose I found these website: http://www.made.com or this one http://www.elegantsteps.co.uk/

I know that both are based on Magento, And everyone else know it's easy install wappalyzer and it will tell you which frameworks have been used.

As I have already identified that these websites are built on magento.

Now I want to know what theme is being used ?

So my question here is:

**Is there any technique or any website or any other thing through which we could know or Identify the theme (which is being used in these websites).**

Once Again I don't want to know about framework as I have already Identified it, I want to know how to Identify theme in magento based running website.

**P.S:**  I don't have access to these websites, All I want to know is what theme is being used. just like we do for wordpress by using wordpress theme detector.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me.

Thanks,
Arth

Answer (score 7):

Look at the HTML source in your browser ("View Source") and search for `skin/frontend`, which is followed by PACKAGE/THEME, where PACKAGE is usually the name of the theme and THEME is usually `default` or contains site specific changes.

In this example it is `webtise/default`:

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: in this case its website/default, so what does this means ? does it mean it is custom build theme ?