# I want to know the name of the theme in the below site

Tags: theme

I want to know the name of the theme of this website https://www.nappadori.com/ .

I have seen this question [How to check which theme is being used in a magento based website.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134465/how-to-check-which-theme-is-being-used-in-a-magento-based-website) to detect the theme but the theme folder is named as the name of the website.

Comment: whether you got your solution

Answer (score 2):

Usually developers modify the theme name.so it is difficult to find the original theme name.we can search for similar themes and find the best that suits. may be nappa_dori is the the theme name but we cannot say it confidently

Answer (score 0):

Please open source code. You can find your theme name after frontend/default/ than **nappa_dori** is your theme name see below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.nappadori.com/skin/frontend/default/**nappa_dori**/css-live/jquery.fancyb
```

Comment: nappa_dori is theme name but it's may not be the actual theme they have been able to renamed that